# UNIX paths -- what do ., ~, .. prefixes mean?

Tags: unix, filesystems

`/home/ise` is my shell-base folder.

What are the differnces between those lines ?

Thanks.

```
/home/ise

./home/ise

~/home/ise

../home/ise
```

Comment: Have you tried them all?

Comment: This is by no means a question specific to bash -- other than `~`, these use no shell constructs whatsoever, and are a question about UNIX in general. And `~` is not specific to bash -- all POSIX shells support it. (Actually, your home directory isn't a shell-native value either -- it's part of your operating system account's settings, and it would still exist and be meaningful even if your OS didn't use a native UNIX shell at all).

Answer (score 1):

```
/home/ise   # absolute path (often "/" is the root of your hard drive)

./home/ise  # relative to current directory

~/home/ise  # relative to the current users home directory

../home/ise # relative to the current directory's parent folder
```

Comment: A file system can consist of multiple disks, and a single disk can contain multiple file systems. `/home/ise` is simply an absolute path in a given file system.

Comment: @chepner yep good point, i was only thinking about the usual "personal machine with 1 hard drive and FS". I updated the answer, does that sound better?

Comment: @chepner: /home/ise is an absolute path in the _root_ filesystem, not a "given" one. If the current root ("given fs") is also mounted elsewhere, perhaps over nfs (mountpoint<>/), then the directory we call /home/ise will no more be absolute to the remote machine.

Comment: It's worth calling out that the `~/...` form is a shell construct, whereas all the others have meaning to the native filesystem, operating system, &c. directly.

Answer (score 0):

/home/ise - specifies path from disk

./home/ise  - same as above, the `.` indicates current directory

~/home/ise - `~` indicates from home directory

../home/ise - `..` specifies parent directory